# Is it possible to print a string at a certain screen position inside IDLE?

Tags: python, python-idle

It's a strange and silly question I know, but I'm curious because I don't know that much about python and how it works.
From the terminal or when you use IDLE, is there any way to print a string at a certain screen position?

I'll try to explain this better: Do you remember the old days when you used to make small programs in Basic, maybe on a Commodore 64, Apple II or ZX Spectrum?
During that days if you wanted to print a string at a certain position you used to write something like this:

10 LOCATE 30, 40 : PRINT "hello world"

I'm just curious to know if there's any way to tell python to print a string at a certain position, and if there's a way to know how many columns and how many rows can be actually displayed inside the IDLE window.

I've also made a mockup draw, to explain this concept.

[image: Mockup screen to explain what I mean]

Comment: If you want anything this fancy, let go of IDLE and embrace curses. Or re-implement half of it yourself, which is quite some pain.

Comment: If you are going to use curses, try the blessed it has loads of easy functions to perform tasks the same tasks https://pypi.org/project/blessed/ (Note this comment is not for the original poster of the question but people ending up here after a google search)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't know if this works on IDLE, but it does in any normal terminal:

```
import sys
def print_there(x, y, text):
     sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (x, y, text))
     sys.stdout.flush()
```

This uses [Ansi-Escape Sequences](https://web.archive.org/web/20210226122732/http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)

Comment: @Caltor: Follow the link above which explains Ansi Escape Sequences. These are interpreted by the terminal software.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.  Although I had to reverse x and y.

Comment: I got this instead, doesn't it work for window console? 
    >>> print_there(0,0,'hello')
    ←7←[0;0fhello←8>>>

Comment: The link to Ansi-Escape Sequences page does not work anymore. You can use this one instead: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the issue raised by [@user3431399](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3431399/user3431399), you first need [to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences). I got the same problem as [@user3431399](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3431399/user3431399) on my Windows 10 terminal and I solved it by following the [solution recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56150498) by [@Daniel De Léon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980442/daniel-de-le%c3%b3n). That is, I logged in as administrator at the windows prompt (cmd command). Then I copied, pasted, and ran the command.

> [REG ADD HKCU\CONSOLE /f /v VirtualTerminalLevel /t REG_DWORD /d 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56150498)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [cursor position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences)
ANSI escape code.

```
print("\033[{0};{1}H{2}".format(30, 40, "Hello world"))
```

or

```
print("\033[{0};{1}f{2}".format(30, 40, "Hello world"))
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer a bit more to understand your way?

Answer (score -1):

Use Tkinter to make it perfect by select under frame and provide row and column number to display your output