# Problem with simple RGB animation in python

Tags: python, sys

i am trying to make a simple RGB animation with python, and I am having some difficulties.

The problem really is the output, that is completely wrong as what I wanted.

Code:

```
def animation(message):
    def yuh():
        while True:
            colors = dict(Fore.__dict__.items())
            for color, i in zip(colors.keys(), range(20)):
                sys.stdout.write(colors[color] + message + "\r")
                sys.stdout.flush()
                sys.stdout.write('\b')
                time.sleep(0.5)
    threading.Thread(target=yuh).start()


def menu():
    animation("Hello Please select a option !")
    print("1 -- Test")
    qa = input("Answer?: ")

    if qa == 1:
        print("You did it !")
        sys.exit()

menu()
```

Output:

```py
1 -- Test
Hello Please select a option !a option !
```

My initial thoughts werw that the output looked like this:

```py
Hello Please select a option !
1 -- Test
Answer?:
```

How am I able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the cursor stays where the last print/input function ended. So after line 3 of menu(), the cursor is at the end of "Answer?:", where the message is printed first, the after the "\r" carriage return pulls the cursor to the start of the line. There is a solution though:

```
def animation(message):
        def yuh():
                while True:
                        colors = dict(Fore.__dict__.items())
                        for color, i in zip(colors.keys(), range(20)):
                                sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (0, 0, colors[color] + message + "\r"))
                                sys.stdout.flush()
                                sys.stdout.write('\b')
                                time.sleep(0.5)
        threading.Thread(target=yuh).start()


def menu():
        animation("Hello Please select a option !")
        print("1 -- Test")
        qa = input("Answer?: ")

        if qa == 1:
                print("You did it !")
                sys.exit()

menu()
```

You might need to edit the coordinates but other than that it should work!

Help from:
[Is it possible to print a string at a certain screen position inside IDLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392779/is-it-possible-to-print-a-string-at-a-certain-screen-position-inside-idle)

Comment: The output is a little bit better, but still not great... Output (I changed the coordinates to 1,1) ```8llo Please select a option !
1 -- Test

Answer?: 7```

Comment: EDIT: I still didn't understanded very well the coordinates, so i maybe wrong.

Comment: After some time, a found a ANSII code that worked, here is it: \x1b7\x1b\x1b[F\x1b[F[%d;%df%s\x1b8